# Travel from Schengen Area back to home country

Tags: schengen

I am traveling from Italy to my home country of India and my residence permit might expire by the time of my travel.

If I am not wrong, I have to surrender my residence permit before I leave Italy.

Currently there are no direct flights from Italy and I have to transit at Amsterdam.

Will there be any issue at Amsterdam airport if all I have is my Indian Passport?

Comment: By 'traveling' do you mean a short visit or effectively moving to India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be, you will have to go through exit immigration at Amsterdam, where border guards are supposed to check the length of time you have been in the Schengen area. A regular Indian visitor should have a visa and an entry stamp less than 90 days old. The residence permit would be useful to prove this rule doesn't apply to you and you have done nothing wrong. Are you sure you have to surrender it?

Comment: I am not sure. I heard from some people that I should deregister myself as a resident. I have been in Italy for 3 years.

Comment: @Morpheus deregistration as a resident does not necessarily require surrendering your permit, though I do not know specifically how this is handled in Italy.  It may even be possible to deregister after you arrive in India.

Comment: @phoog Thanks! You are right!

Comment: @Morpheus you're welcome.  Please consider accepting this answer or, if you have more detail to add, posting your own answer and accepting that.