# Traveling from Italy on an expired residence permit

Tags: resident-permit, italy

I am traveling back to India from Italy and my residence permit is expiring a day before my intended day of travel. I don’t intend to travel back to Italy immediately. Is this okay or will I face any issues in future if I want to travel to another European country for work? I am leaving without stepping in another Schengen country.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Travel from Schengen Area back to home country](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/22436/travel-from-schengen-area-back-to-home-country)